# SQL duplicate rows query in Linq

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following sql query to count duplicates in a table MachineLog. This query i execute directly in my project with ExecuteSqlCommand. But the execution time takes more than 1 minute.

```
select Count(*) from MachineLog where Id in
    (
    select Id from (
    select *,
    RANK() OVER ( PARTITION BY CompanyId, DeviceEnrollNo, InOutDate, InOutTime, MachineNo ORDER BY Id DESC )rank
    From MachineLog
    )T
    where rank>1
    )
```

Now i want to use this query in Linq as there is option `Any` which works faster. I am having LinqPad but it converts Linq to SQL & not SQL to Linq. And Linqer is already expired from my system.

Can somebody help?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one if you just want to take count why are you using * though ?
Might this help:

```
select Count(*) from MachineLog where Id in
    (
    select Id from (
    select Id,
    RANK() OVER ( PARTITION BY CompanyId, DeviceEnrollNo, InOutDate, InOutTime, MachineNo ORDER BY Id DESC )rank
    From MachineLog
    )T
    where rank>1
    )
```

Comment: I tried this query it is taking same time as the one before. I am basically trying to convert this query in Linq so that i can use `Any` instead of `Count`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using CTE

;WITH cte AS (
 SELECT,ID
RANK() OVER ( PARTITION BY CompanyId, DeviceEnrollNo, InOutDate, InOutTime, MachineNo ORDER BY Id DESC ) AS rank
    From MachineLog
        )
        SELECT Count(*) from MachineLog m
        JOIN CTE c ON c.id=m.ID
        WHERE c.rank >1